# change class type for multiple vars

Tags: r

What is the best way to covert multiple var class types at once? For example all class types that are "character" to "numeric", and if they are not "character" type the class type stays the same.

Comment: Assuming your vars are in a data.frame, `DF[my_vars] <- lapply(DF[my_vars], as.numeric)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` is a `data.frame`, this function returns another `data.frame` where `character` rows are converted to `numeric` and other rows remain the same:

```
convertRows <- function(df, name='character', FUN=as.numeric) as.data.frame(
  lapply(df, function(x) if (class(x)==name) FUN(x) else x))
```

This is an example of the function applied to a `data.frame` with `character` and `logical` rows:

```
> df <- data.frame(a='1', b=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr "1"
 $ b: logi FALSE
> str(convertRows(df))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num 1
 $ b: logi FALSE
```